# how to integrate AWS services for language without sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS provides SDK only for some languages. How could I integrate AWS services in an application for which an official SDK is not provided. Eg `C` of `Scala` or `Rust`? I know that for Scala, some aws sdk projects are available but as they are individual contributions (and not aws releases), I am reluctant to use them.

Comment: For Scala, just use the Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

All the SDKs do is wrap some minimal interface around the API calls made to the AWS servers. For any service you wish to integrate into your application, just head over to their API documentation, and write your own codes/wrappers.

For eg. [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) takes you to the API reference for EC2 service.

Comment: There are a few things you might want ( like xml schema for the messages) that aren't fully detailed.  In this case, you could look at one of the already implemented languages for hints

Comment: Also, you have to understand how signatures work, and how they change depending on the service.

Answer (score 0):

In the early days of AWS, we needed an SDK for C++. At that time an SDK for C++ did not exist, so I wrote one based upon the REST API. This is no easy task as the Amazon API is huge and by the time you complete coding for one service, you have to go back and update with all of the AWS feature improvements and changes. This seems like a never ending loop.

Several of the AWS SDKs were started by third party developers and then contributed to Amazon as open source projects. If you have a popular language that you feel that others could benefit from, start an open source project and get everyone involved. It could become an official project if there is enough demand. Ping me if you do as I might be interested in contributing.

Comment: you might want to check out https://github.com/dwhjames/aws-wrap or https://github.com/seratch/AWScala or https://github.com/awslabs/aws-scala-sdk